# Dspace 7 using docker compose: Encounter error when loading data

Tags: docker, dspace

I was following the setup procedure for Dspace 7 by following the instructions [here](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSPACE/Try+out+DSpace+7#TryoutDSpace7-InstallboththeUserInterfaceandRESTAPIlocally) but encounter the following error when I ran this step

`docker-compose -p d7 -f docker/cli.yml -f ./docker/cli.ingest.yml run --rm dspace-cli`

Anyone encountered this before?

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Error logs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.dspace.content.authority.ChoiceAuthorityServiceImpl.getAuthorityByFieldKeyCollection(ChoiceAuthorityServiceImpl.java:488)
    at org.dspace.content.authority.ChoiceAuthorityServiceImpl.getLabel(ChoiceAuthorityServiceImpl.java:178)
    at org.dspace.content.authority.ChoiceAuthorityServiceImpl.getLabel(ChoiceAuthorityServiceImpl.java:173)
    at org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceMetadataBrowseIndexingPlugin.additionalIndex(SolrServiceMetadataBrowseIndexingPlugin.java:178)
    at org.dspace.discovery.indexobject.IndexFactoryImpl.buildDocument(IndexFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at org.dspace.discovery.indexobject.DSpaceObjectIndexFactoryImpl.buildDocument(DSpaceObjectIndexFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.dspace.discovery.indexobject.ItemIndexFactoryImpl.buildDocument(ItemIndexFactoryImpl.java:134)
    at org.dspace.discovery.indexobject.ItemIndexFactoryImpl.buildDocument(ItemIndexFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceImpl.update(SolrServiceImpl.java:165)
    at org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceImpl.indexContent(SolrServiceImpl.java:155)
    at org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceImpl.updateIndex(SolrServiceImpl.java:322)
    at org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceImpl.updateIndex(SolrServiceImpl.java:309)
    at org.dspace.discovery.IndexClient.internalRun(IndexClient.java:130)
    at org.dspace.scripts.DSpaceRunnable.run(DSpaceRunnable.java:104)
    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.executeScript(ScriptLauncher.java:149)
    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.handleScript(ScriptLauncher.java:131)
    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:98)
```

[Full Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi3NK.jpg)